# BFcache disabled by unload events (Back-Forward cache)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, caching, browser-cache

**(Note: FireFox only)**

*The Back-Forward cache is a caching system in firefox that runs when the back button is clicked. It will then simply use the DOM from the previous page that is in it's cache instead of reloading the entire page (and re-requesting files).*

I'm using piwik (an analytics service), that requires a tracking code snippet to be added to the footer. Upon adding this, the back-forward cache no longer works.

It is my understanding that, if there is an unload event (or beforeunload) the bfcache is automatically disabled. This is likely what is happening here.

Is there anything I can add to make the BFCache work anyway?

To make matters worse, **I cannot add any custom code below the piwik code**. That one is always last.

I added the code displayed below to try and remove any unload events that are registered, but the BFcache is still not working.

```
$(window).unbind('beforeunload');
$(window).unbind('unload');
window.onbeforeunload = null;
window.onunload = null;
```

I also tried:

```
function UnloadHandler() { 
    window.removeEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false); 
}

window.addEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false);

$(window).unload(function () { $(window).unbind('unload'); });
```

but this too does not work.

I have placed some samples online. Remember to test this with Firefox:

**this one shows a working BFcache**  (you will get an different alert based on whether or not the back button was clicked)

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/bfcache/a.html

**Loaded piwik, BFCache no longer works**

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/bfcache/b.html

**Loaded piwik, tried to unset onload event, but still not working**

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/bfcache/c.html

**Using unloadhandler**

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/bfcache/d.html

**Suggestions by @roasted**

http://users.telenet.be/prullen/bfcache/e.html
http://users.telenet.be/prullen/bfcache/f.html

More information about BFCache:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching

You can see another demo of the behavior here:

http://www.twmagic.com/misc/cache.html

If you add dom elements, and click the first link, then return - the dom elements are still there. However, if you add an onload or beforeunload event that is not the case. Again, test this in firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm completly lose on what you are trying to do because i don't know tools/plugin you are using, but couldn't you instead capture event: `window.addEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, true);` ???

Comment: @roasted this question has nothing to do with piwik, it's just an example of a tool that adds unload events. I don't need to add more like you are suggesting. I need to get rid of all of them or otherwise BFCache won't work. I added another example, see above, of me trying to do that, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @roasted - tried your suggestion: http://users.telenet.be/prullen/bfcache/e.html - but the BFCache still doesn't seem to work. :/

Comment: The thing is i cannot see any difference with the page supposed to work and pages which you tell doesn't work. How can you see difference? Clicking on link then back button of browser? For me all pages show the alert(). I'm on FF 22.0

Comment: As i can see in piwik source code, it is using javascript, not jquery and beforeunload event. I'd say then try that: `$(window).on('load',function(){this.onbeforeunload = null;});` But this need to work that beforeunload from piwik is setted before onload event of window is fired. Try and see

Comment: @roasted; tried it - http://users.telenet.be/prullen/bfcache/f.html - again no success. What difference there is? Load example a.html and you'll see there are in fact two different alerts. One for normal page load, and one if you press the back button. It only works in example a so far.

Comment: For me on page a.html, there is always one same alert() for initial load or when back to page.

Comment: @roasted - are you using firefox? This only works for firefox.

Comment: FF 22.0 on win 7. You better have to provide a jsfiddle which reproduce your issue

Comment: @roasted  - just tested it on FF22 on win7 also (via browserstack.com) - works as I said, two different alerts (back button or not). You probably have some extension loaded that also adds unload events which makes it fail even in the default example provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to enable BFCache you need to remove `beforeunload` event listener. It should be the same listener which was added by Piwik code, otherwise [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) will do nothing.

That listener is unreachable outside of the Piwik's source, so one does not simply remove it.

But, if you have a possibility to insert code *before* the Piwik, you can try to [override `addEventListener`](http://jsfiddle.net/mwMBf/2/), track added handlers and expose function to remove all tracked handlers at once.

Comment: Is it known that Firefox Back-Forward cache and WebKit Page Cache will be re-enabled for the current page if the handlers are cleared before the navigation takes place?

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis The code checks if page is eligible for BFCache at the moment of navigation, so if handlers are cleared before that moment, they won't disable cache. Similar technique with code example for IndexedDB is described here: https://web.dev/i18n/en/bfcache/#always-close-open-connections-before-the-user-navigates-away